# PHP - Remove a complete string that starts with "author"

Tags: php, string, replace, contains

How to remove a complete string that always starts with "author-" but after hyphen could be something diffrent on each page.

Comment: No research effort, this or similar has been asked plenty of times.

Comment: I searched the web for about 30 min, sry my english isnt that good, and I couldnt find a solution, so I thought it would be ok to ask in on website where every minutes hundred of questions are asked, without getting flamed ...

Comment: Why use regular expresion, where you can just cut string with `substr()` or explode it to first `-` with `explode()`.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the following `preg_replace` expression

```
preg_replace("/^author-.*$/", "", $field);
```

Comment: Simple. +1. Shouldn't there be a space at the end? or a period etc.

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ A string does not always end at a space or period character…

Comment: Ok so whats the solution then? This will remove everything after author-  even the next words. Try it

Comment: The question was "The complete string" so that includes spaces and next words.

Comment: @putvande fine in that case, I just thought it was that exact word which needed to be removed which started with `author-`

Answer (score 1):

```
if( false !== strpos( $string, 'author-' ) )
{
    unset( $string );
}
```

or

```
$string = preg_replace( '/author-.*/', '', $string );
```

(not tested)

Comment: preg_replace worked perfect, thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use [pcre](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) for it.

```
$string = "
title-one
author-two
date-three
who-author-
";

echo preg_replace('/^author\-.*$/m', '', $string);
```

I am using [m modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to process every line separately